# XML de-serialization using xml element/attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Need your help in setting the xml attributes for XML deserialization.

This is my input xml:

```
<form>
<question id="QnA">
<answer>AnswerforA</answer>
</question>
<question id="QnB">
<answer>AnswerforB</answer>
</question>
<question id="QnC">
<answer>AnswerforC</answer>
</question>
</form>
```

The ids of each question element tag correspond to a class property and its value is the innertext of the corresponding answer element.

The .cs file will look like

```
 public class Test
{

   private string qnaAns;    
   private string qnbAns;   
   private string qncAns;   

    public string QnA
    {
    get{ return qnaAns;}
    set{qnaAns = value;}
    }

    public string QnB
    {
    get{ return qnbAns;}
    set{qnbAns = value;}
    }

    public string QnC
    {
    get{ return qncAns;}
    set{qncAns = value;}
    }
}
```

and I use the follwing code for deserialization

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));

XmlReader xr = new xmlReader(inputxml);

Test t = ser.Deserialize(xr) as Test;
```

Please let me know how to set the XML element/attribute for the Test class to achieve this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm a little too lazy to look through your code and figure out what you're having trouble with, so please let us know what's the issue you're having.

Comment: You should either structure your DTO to represent the data you are trying to serialize, or you would have to implement `IXmlSerializable` (not fun). See Matt's answer for an example of the first (and correct, IMO) option.

Answer (score 2):

```
 [XmlRoot("form")]
    public class Form
    {
        [XmlElement("question")]
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

        public Form()
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>();
        }
    }
    public struct Question
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("answer")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

Then to serialize, I use the following extensions:

```
public static bool XmlSerialize<T>(this T item, string fileName) 
        { 
            return item.XmlSerialize(fileName, true); 
        } 
        public static bool XmlSerialize<T>(this T item, string fileName, bool removeNamespaces) 
        { 
            object locker = new object(); 

            XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); 
            xmlns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty); 

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings(); 
            settings.Indent = true; 
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; 

            lock (locker) 
            { 
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings)) 
                { 
                    if (removeNamespaces) 
                    { 
                        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, xmlns); 
                    } 
                    else { xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, item); } 

                    writer.Close(); 
                } 
            } 

            return true; 
        } 
        public static T XmlDeserialize<T>(this string s) 
        { 
            object locker = new object(); 
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s); 
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader); 
            try 
            { 
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 
                lock (locker) 
                { 
                    T item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader); 
                    reader.Close(); 
                    return item; 
                } 
            } 
            finally 
            { 
                if (reader != null) 
                { reader.Close(); } 
            } 
        } 
        public static T XmlDeserialize<T>(this FileInfo fileInfo) 
        { 
            string xml = string.Empty; 
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
            { 
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) 
                { 
                    return sr.ReadToEnd().XmlDeserialize<T>(); 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Hope this helps.

PS - The extensions came from my library on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MBGExtensionsLibrary.aspx

Comment: You can deserialize like this:  `Form form = new FileInfo("c:\\test.xml").XmlDeserialize<Form>();`

Comment: not sure the extension methods are really worth it, but the overall approach (having a DTO model that mirrors the xml) is absolutely the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my intention is not to have the List<Question> with two elements inside. Based on your code , I have to set the QnA property as   public string QnA
        {
            get { return Questions[Questions.FindIndex(t => t.ID=="QnA")].Answer; }
            set { ; }
        }     .. Is it possible to set the properties directly? Thanks.

Comment: Also, Also, is it possible to specify another parameter "section" along with "question" for the question object i.e

The form can also be

        <form>
        <question id="QnA">
        <answer>AnswerforA</answer>
        </question>
        <section id="QnB">
        <answer>AnswerforB</answer>
        </section>
        </form>