# How to specify the XML element tag to include all the specified xml nodes in deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I got answers for serializing my class in the below link

[XML de-serialization using xml element/attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794366/xml-de-serialization-using-xml-element-attributes)

But I have to include all the elements irrespective of their position in the XML.

XML:

```
     <form>
     <question id="QnA">
        <answer>AnswerforA</answer>
     </question>
     <question id="QnB">
        <answer>AnswerforB</answer>
     </question>
     <question id="QnC">
        <answer>AnswerforC1</answer>
     </question>
     <section>
         <question id="Qnd">
           <answer>Answerford</answer>
         </question>
      </section>
    </form>
```

.cs:

```
  [XmlRoot("form")]
  public class Form
  {
        [XmlElement("question")]
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

        public Form()
        {
              Questions = new List<Question>();
        }
  }
  public struct Question
  {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("answer")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
  }
```

In this, I can get the three elements QnA,QnB,QnC in the Questions list.

How to specify the XML element such that it includes all the question elements under  i.e to include the QnD element also in the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your project:

```
public class Section
{
  [XmlElement("question")]
  public List<Question> Questions {get; set;}

  public Section()
  {
     Questions = new List<Question>();
  }
}
```

The modify the `Form` class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("form")]       
public class Form       
{       
    [XmlElement("question")]       
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }  

    [XmlElement("section")]     
    public List<Section> Sections {get; set;}

    public Form()       
    {       
          Questions = new List<Question>();       
          Sections = new List<Section>();
    }       
}
```